# java is not running

Tags: android, json

Hi I am new to Android and i am developing one app in which i will send request to server and get json data.The problem is that when receive response fron server and when i trying to get that i get one exception 
java.lang.String cannot converted to JSONobject

Comment: your image is json object and you have image as String..error it self saying

Comment: how to slove the problem sir please help me

Answer (score 0):

Your server returned incorrect json-data. There are extra `"` that should be removed.

It should look similar to

```
[{
    "image": "http://eprintpost.com/images/savepreflab/uploadSave/69120e7d-31e0-46ac-bf07-e86778bc2866.jpg",
    "productid": "255",
    "oldprice": "250",
    "city": "Pune",
    "price": "200",
    "labname": "Emotions",
    "productname": "Sublimation Bag (6058)"
}, {
    "image": "http://eprintpost.com/images/savepreflab/uploadSave/48e9420c-3bd2-4c89-91a3-0de3346c072f.jpg",
    "productid": "481",
    "oldprice": "1000",
    "city": "Coimbatore",
    "price": "500",
    "labname": "savithri photo house",
    "productname": "camera toploader 450AW Black"
}, {
    "image": "http://eprintpost.com/images/savepreflab/uploadSave/741e6549-94be-439d-b823-0bd8b26bb0ce.jpg",
    "productid": "556",
    "oldprice": "1000",
    "city": "Dharwad",
    "price": "400",
    "labname": "Foto Magic Studio And Lab",
    "productname": "07.jpg"
}]
```

Comment: could you please tell me where is the extra " So after which word there is extra "

Comment: how to rwmove that extra "

Comment: Your server should send correct data. Probably it generates json in wrong way

Answer (score 0):

**Could you put all your error log cat ?** Where is exactly throw this error

```
type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Your error is parsing from String to JSONObject so let focus on which lines make a parsing to JSONObject

Comment: Error Found at   JSONObject c = offer.getJSONObject(i); line

Comment: error found at   JSONObject c = offer.getJSONObject(i); line and About MUG String Mug=Mug;

Comment: Let Log.d(TAG, "i : " + i); before your error line to see what is type of String in i . I think the String in i is not a JSON so it couldn't parse.

Comment: the value of i is first value of i that is 0

Comment: Do you solve your error ? Where is the code ? I think you should tick a debug point at that line and run debug to see what happened at that line.

Comment: The java doc say that the JSONArray.getJSONObject(index i) Throws:

JSONException - If there is no value for the index or if the value is not a JSONObject

So let check your JSON return from server is it JSON format or not.